# Add images to blog with ImageField?

Tags: media, nodes, 5

Using drupal 5.x.  I have a content type I created called "Blog Entry"  it has no fields other than the standard title and body.  Now I want to be able to place images at arbitrary points in the body of the blog entry and have them appear.  I already have ImageField and ImageCache installed for use with another content type.  Is there a way I can use those two modules to achieve my goal or do I need to install something like the Image module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article which describes one method of doing this.  Looks promising not sure if it's the best way.   For one I'm not immediately sure how to handle multiple images.  [How To: Inline Images with ImageField and ImageCache using HTML](http://drupal.org/node/593518)

**UPDATE**

Yes I can confirm this works.  You can use a single ImageField and check the "Multiple values" checkbox when creating the image field to support multiple images.  I named my field "blog_images".  Then on the "Display Fields" tab I set the label, teaser, and Full values to all be `"<hidden>"`